# Integration By parts question.

Tags: calculus, integration

If the Integration by Parts Formula is derived by the derivative of the product rule, can we use the derivative of the quotient rule in Integration by Parts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For illustration purposes, can you provide an example of where use of the quotient rule, rather than the product rule would lead to an easier application of integration by parts?  The quotient rule is simply a simplification of the product rule, since $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)\left[g(x)\right]^{-1}.$$  This equals $$\left\{\left[g(x)\right]^{-1} \times f'(x)\right\} ~+~ \left\{(-1) \times \left[g(x)\right]^{-2} \times g'(x) \times f(x)\right\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

OCOVALOCO's integration by parts rule....

$$
\int \frac{du}{v} = \frac{u}{v} + \int\frac{u\,dv}{v^2}
$$

Obtain it starting with the quotient rule
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' = \frac{u'}{v} - \frac{uv'}{v^2}
$$
then integrating.

Comment: Clever, I like this OCOVALOCO's integration by parts rule!

Answer (score 1):

The quotient rule is a special case of when the product rule is applied to a quotient:
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=f(x)\frac{1}{g(x)},$$
which gives the well-known formula
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\frac{1}{g(x)}\right)
=f'(x)\frac{1}{g(x)}-f(x)\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}
=f'(x)\frac{g(x)}{g(x)^2}-f(x)\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}
=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}.$$